# SUM of attributes across different ables and JOIN

Tags: sql

I am currently learning sql and have the following problems.

Suppose I have two very similar tables,

```
TABLE A
NAME CNT
A    1
B    2


TABLE B 
NAME CNT 
A    2
C    5
```

Now I want to join the two tables and sum up the cnt is the name is the same

```
RESULT 
NAME CNT 
A     3
B     2
C     5
```

anyone can help to provide some hint on the good way to go for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(CNT) FROM
(
   SELECT NAME, CNT FROM TABLE_A
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NAME, CNT FROM TABLE_B
) TAB
GROUP BY NAME;
```

[Working Fiddle For ORACLE Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/011f1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Union the tables together in a temp table, group by the name to be unique and then sum up the values

```
select name, sum(cnt) as cnt
from 
(
   select name, cnt from A
   union all
   select name, cnt from B
) tmp
group by name
```